How to host android emulator on web like Project IDX does?
Project IDX
As you can see, there is an android emulator running on the web, which I can interact with.
I wanted to ask how can I replicate this? I heard somewhere that browserstack has kept physical phones which they stream.
Can I use something like a virtual emulator?
I want to replicate the Project IDX Android emulator

As of now BrowserStack does not offer the functionality to live stream devices on ProjectIDX during development for preview,
If the requirement is to interact with the devices while running an automation script then we can use interactive debugging feature in BS.
reference:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/interactive-session

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
